# How to find missing values in table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hey I try to get missing values from my table, but I have no idea how I can get it without CTE and recursion. 
Below is my current code, but it works with recursion as I said before.

```
DROP TABLE #temp;
CREATE TABLE #temp (
    val INT NULL   
);
DECLARE @val AS INT = 1;

WHILE @val <= 10
BEGIN
    INSERT #temp (val)
    SELECT cast((RAND()*10) as int);
    SET @val = @val + 1;
END

SELECT *
FROM   #temp;

WITH CTE AS
(

    SELECT nMin = MIN(t.val), MAX(t.val) as 'nMax' 
    FROM #temp t
    UNION ALL

    SELECT nMin + 1, nMax 
    FROM CTE
    WHERE nMin < nMax
)


SELECT c.nMin
FROM CTE c
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT val
    FROM #temp
    WHERE c.nMin = val
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a list of numbers with no missing values, so you can do an anti-join against.

Now you're trying to generate those values with recursion. It's much more efficient to use ROW_NUMBER against a system table. You can cross join the system table to get as many numbers as you want, and use a TOP clause to limit the results. Even in a database with no user tables, there will be system defined objects.

I left your code in so you can compare the differences.
If you use this often enough, it may be worthwhile to have a numbers table in your db. Also called a tally table.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (
    val INT NULL   
);
DECLARE @val AS INT = 1;

WHILE @val <= 10
BEGIN
    INSERT #temp (val)
    SELECT cast((RAND()*10) as int);
    SET @val = @val + 1;
END

SELECT *
FROM   #temp ORDER BY val;

WITH CTE AS
(

    SELECT nMin = MIN(t.val), MAX(t.val) as 'nMax' 
    FROM #temp t
    UNION ALL

    SELECT nMin + 1, nMax 
    FROM CTE
    WHERE nMin < nMax
)

,CTE_NUMBERS AS
(
    SELECT TOP(10)
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1 as d)) as nMin
    FROM sys.all_objects AS a
    CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS b
)

SELECT c.nMin
FROM CTE_NUMBERS c
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT val
    FROM #temp
    WHERE c.nMin = val
)

DROP TABLE #temp
```